# When mounting an S3 bucket on an ubuntu EC2 instance with S3FS, SSH connection is not possible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ssh

As stated above, I mounted an S3 bucket with S3FS on an ubuntu instance that I was able to SSH to, and when I restarted the instance, SSH connection to the instance was no longer possible.

ssh command

```
ssh -i "pem filename" ubuntu@"ec2-domain-name"
```

Error message

```
ssh: connect to host "ec2-domain name" port 22: Connection refused
```

This event did not occur until 2/28/2022, but started to occur on 3/1/2022.
Please let me know if you know the solution or if you have encountered the same issue.

Comment: Almost certainly unrelated to s3fs, I would think.

Comment: The instance didn't come back online after the reboot.  You could investigate the console output to see what's going on, clone the EBS volume to a new instance and check it for logs, or just terminate the instance and bring up a new one.

Comment: You can use `ssh -vvv` to obtain more debugging information.